# Редактируемые строки в JS + HTML

Tags: javascript, html, строки, post

Обычно в JS я не лезу, но тут пришлось изучить(в проект добавить, и скажу достаточно интересная штука). Так вот, мне надо генерировать HTML код(табличку), вроде всё хорошо, но есть одно НО. В HTML вызывается JS функция, в которую передаётся переменная(обычный текст). Если текст без пробелов, то всё нормуль, но если появляются пробелы, то начинается, что то не понятное, может кто разъяснит что я не так делаю)
Код и ошибка:

Код для создания таблички

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj['warehouse_client_info']).length + 1; i++){

                        click_data = `'ordering|${obj['warehouse_client_info'][i][0]}|${obj['warehouse_client_info'][i][2]}'`;
                        console.log(click_data)
                        document.getElementById("table_info").innerHTML += `<tr><td id='name'>${obj['warehouse_client_info'][i][0]}</td><td id='count'>${obj['warehouse_client_info'][i][1]}</td><td><a onclick=order(${click_data})>Заказать</a></td><tr>`;
                    }
```

Код функции для отправки POST запроса на сервер

```
function order(text){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http:/IP/index', false);
            console.log(text)
            xhr.send([String(text)]);
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            } else {
                console.log('!OK!')
                alert('Ваш запрос успешно отправлен')
            }

        };
```

Фоточки:

[image: Ошибка в консольке]
[image: HTML]

На 2 скрине, видно что появляются ковычки, хотя их нигде нет, откуда они и как их убрать, а то JS думает что это переменные.

Заранее спасибо! Всем успешной трудовой недели!

Comment: Не обращайте внимания на 'kek', думал может ошибка в 1 слове

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое происходит из-за того, что вы генерируете невалидный html, а браузер пытается его починить.

Значения аттирбутов должны быть обёрнуты в двойные кавычки.

```
let html = `<a onclick="order(${click_data})">Заказать</a>`
                       ^                    ^
```

Comment: Спасибо) После python, немного потерял бдительность)

Comment: Дополню: корявых буржуйских кавычек ````, если они не являются частью текста, в коде существовать не должно!

Comment: @Инквизитор, а можно про это подробнее? Насколько я знаю, они позволяют делать подстановку переменных в строку, а так же разрешают переносы строк. Примеры: [imgur.com/a/N70katj](https://imgur.com/a/N70katj)

Comment: Ну, на самом деле они допустимы, просто очень легко ошибиться и, например, закрыть открывающую косую кавычку прямой - и будет ошибка. Плюс на многих платформах они в коде не дозволяются, а рассматриваются как текст, даром что все построено на яваскрипте. В общем, лучше использовать прямые кавычки - одиночные и парные - а косые оставить для `подсветки кода` здесь.

Comment: @Инквизитор, имхо, это всё же достаточно спорное утверждение. Перепутать кавычки не позволит ide. Да и когда вы последний раз ставили кавычки не парами? Так же ошибка в общем достаточно тривиальна что бы легко её найти. [Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) были введены в ES2015, т.е. 5 лет назад и за это время их поддержку добавили все современные платформы, а в случаях когда нужно кровь из носу поддерживать старые платформы обычно используется какой-нибудь Babel

Comment: А вы когда-нибудь пробовали кодить без помощи IDE? Например, когда она заглючила, не установлена, или вообще надо срочно что-то сделать, а все, что вам позволено - Notepad++ ? или, например, когда надо ковыряться в чужом коде или на какой-нибудь специфической платформе, где кавычки уже есть? Да, я постоянно сталкиваюсь с необходимостью вставлять кавычки не парами, в тепличных условиях работаю очень редко. Просто поверьте, два вида кавычек лучше, чем три, особенно когда они так похожи.